# proof of real number between two real numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to prove that for any two real numbers that are not equal, you can find a real number between them. I have tried to add two random numbers together and show that it produces a real number.

Comment: If $a<b$, then $a<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$.

Comment: Have you tried averaging?

Answer (score 2):

As both @Batominovski and @Jahan-Claes noted, if you average two real numbers you will get a third real number that is between the first two.

Comment: Batominovski and Jahan-Claes, if you add an answer I'll delete this one, as you two came up with the answer first.